# TextField Disappearing After resizing window Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

TextField Disappearing After resizing window in Flutter.
Any Solutions?

Before ReSizing Window
[image]

After ReSizing Window
[image]

Facing this issue when I'm in a Registration Screen and Going to another screen. After that when I came to registration screen and then resizing it. Textfields are disapparing suddenly. Not getting why this is happening. Below is the attached code please check.

Here is the code of TextFeild,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: widget.height ?? 70,
      width: widget.width,
      child: TextFormField(
        maxLines: widget.maxLine ?? 1,
        enabled: widget.enabled,
        onTap: widget.onTap,
        readOnly: widget.readOnly ?? false,
        cursorColor: AppColor.textColor,
        obscureText: widget.obscureText ?? false,
        validator: widget.validate,
        onChanged: widget.onChanged,
        controller: widget.controller,
        keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
        maxLength: widget.maxLength,
        textInputAction: widget.textInputAction,
        autovalidateMode: widget.autoValidationMode,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          filled: true,
          isDense: true,
          fillColor: AppColor.textFieldFillColor,
          prefixStyle: TextStyle(color: AppColor.textColor),
          counterText: "",
          prefixText: widget.prefixText,
          suffixStyle: widget.suffixStyle,
          floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
          prefixIcon: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
            child: widget.prefixIcon,
          ),
          suffixIcon: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
            child: widget.suffixIcon,
          ),
          prefixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 80),
          suffixIconConstraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 80),
          iconColor: widget.iconColor,
          hintText: widget.hintText,
          hintStyle: widget.hintTextStyle ??
              TextStyle(color: AppColor.black, fontSize: 13),
          labelText: widget.labelText,
          labelStyle: widget.labelTextStyle ??
              TextStyle(color: AppColor.black, fontSize: 13),
          border: InputBorder.none,
          errorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColor.red),
          ),
          focusedErrorBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColor.red),
          ),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: AppColor.primaryColor),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: AppColor.primaryColor),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah! Try this. I have seen in Input Decoration there is a border variable you have written InputBorder.none

```
border: InputBorder.none,
```

Instead of that write below code. Your Problem will be solved.

```
border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 2, color: Colors.black),
          ),
```